# Lsystem 3d Trees, more realism

Tags: opengl, 3d, procedural, l-systems

I try to implement procedural 3d trees in OpenGL using Lsystem.
Up to now I can get these kind of results:
[image]

It looks like a tree, but I would like to improve the result, and get more realistic tree.
Somebody have any ideas to simply add thickness feature to the tree, because for now it's only some "sticks", or structure like leaves ...
I would like to use it in procedural terrain rendring.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're using equal-sized branches at each level, maybe start long at the root segment and reduce the length by x% each level above.

Comment: [Example](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_p_tree.htm).

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping.
I try what you tell and it improved a lot.